# react typescript materialUIを使ったスタイルの当て方

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

環境
・reactとTypescriptを使っています
・デザインはmaterial UIを使っています。
・スタイルlはstyled-componentsで当てています。

わからないこと
Material UIからText Fileldをimportしてきてstyled-componetsを使ってスタイルを当てました。
しかし下記のようなエラーが出てしましました。
わかる人いましたらご教授お願いしたいです

**エラー内容**

```
[ts] Type '{ id: string; variant: "outlined"; label: string; onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<TextFieldProps, "label" | "slot" | "select" | "style" | "title" | "ref" | "type" | "name" | "className" | "classes" | "innerRef" | "children" | "key" | "defaultChecked" | ... 269 more ... | "value"> & Partial<...>, "label" | ... 282 more ... | "value">': style, ref, type, className, and 10 more. [2740]
```

**コード**

```
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  `;

    <StyledTextField
      id="outlined-basic"
      variant="outlined"
      onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setState({ ...state, name: e.target.value})
      }}
    />
```

Comment: [The type of styled-component does not match for &quot;strict: true&quot; · Issue #13921 · mui-org/material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13921#issuecomment-450353391)や[\[styled-components\] Optional types passed down as required · Issue #29832 · DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/29832#issuecomment-544474417)が参考になるように思われます。